# 404 on wordpress multisite Permalink pretty URLs

Tags: permalinks, multisite

I installed a fresh Wordpress site with multisite enabled on AWS ec2 ubuntu instance. I followed all the instructions during the setup. 
My .htaccess looks like below

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]


# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and wp-config looks like below

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'teenjournal.in');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Only the default plain url structure works in multisite mode. Although in single site mode everything works fine.
And adding index.php in the permalink structure works in multisite mode.

```
index.php/%category%/%postname%/
```

My site is hosted at [Teen Journal](https://teenjournal.in)

Answer (score 0):

Edit file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and add this

```
<Directory /var/www/teenjournal.in>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```